# What are the best beginner project using an arduino

Tags: arduino

I'm looking for some cheap beginners projects that show the uses of an arduino.

things like turning on and off an LED

getting back sensor data

...

if anyone has come across useful youtube video tutorials that would be perfect!

that sort of thing

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Start with the sparkfun tutorial [here](http://www.sparkfun.com/commerce/tutorial_info.php?tutorials_id=145) and do a google search. There are tons of different options for starting out with the Arduino, you can try a [starter kit](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/10174). Go on to the [Arduino website](http://arduino.cc/) there is a ton of information there.

Comment: The link to the starter kit is no longer working

Comment: SparkFun also carries the [SparkFun Inventor's Kit for Arduino](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/10173)

Answer (score 8):

You could also check the soon to be release book "Practical Arduino" by Jonathan Oxer and Hugh Blemings. Check out the blog to see some cool projects that is going to be on the book (http://www.practicalarduino.com/).

Answer (score 7):

Yes definately the sparkfun tutorial.  Another source of good starter projects is the free e-book ["The Complete Beginners Guide to the Arduino](http://www.earthshineelectronics.com/files/ASKManualRev4.pdf)

Also worth downloading (or you can buy a hard copy) of the [Arduino Programming Notebook](http://www.lulu.com/content/1108699).  It is a very good walk through of the main code.

Comment: The link to the ebook is no longer working

Comment: This one seems to work http://www.lulu.com/items/volume_63/1108000/1108699/4/print/ARDUINO_NOTEBOOKv6.pdf

Answer (score 7):

I like the "How to Tuesday" projects from Make:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HYUYbN2gRuQ&feature=related

Answer (score 4):

[Linux Format](http://www.linuxformat.co.uk/) had 4 or 5 issues with some Arduino Tutorials in. There are versions of the first two available on Tux Radar [here](http://www.tuxradar.com/content/arduino-hardware-hacking-part-1) and [here](http://www.tuxradar.com/content/arduino-hardware-hacking-part-2). The first one gets some LEDs blinking, whilst the second one showed you how to create a simplified Simon Says game (only 3 LEDs and no sound). Unfortunately they don't appear to have the later ones which extended the project to include sound and a score counter. The same articles also appeared in a Linux Format Special called You Can Code!, so if you can find a copy of that maybe you could follow it there.

Answer (score 4):

I have also been thinking about this. I had thought to give a arduino kit of some sort to family and friends for christmas but wanted to include an interesting project.  This is by no means full answer but here are my current thoughts.

The project should be limited to use a sensor and control (motor). I'd like to have a project which can be applied in every day use. Hence, not something that teaches you the basics of controlling components, but something that tells you how to apply them. For example, a temp. sensor that logs the data to your computer so you can monitor energy efficiency of various parts of your house. Or, an IR sensor and motor to detect when your child gets home late at night. Rig a sensor so that you can monitor when your baby moves in their sleep, and log this. Audio sensor that detects when your partner snores and has a string attached to it which pulls their toe. Etc.

Answer (score 3):

Arduino.cc is the place to go, it has a lot of different tutorials and information.  The arduino is very easy to work with.

Answer (score 1):

Electonic's very own **[tronixstuff](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/1307/tronixstuff)** has a huge, very informative [Arduino tutorial at his website](http://tronixstuff.wordpress.com/tutorials/).

Jeremy Blum also did a [10-part YouTube series](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fCxzA9_kg6s&feature=list_related&playnext=1&list=SPA567CE235D39FA84) on the basics of working with Arduino that I found extremely informative, if a little slow-paced at times (but never lacking in detail).